# Question about order of a sum of entire functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two entire funcions of finite orders $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively. Show that $f=f_1+f_2$ has finite order $\lambda= \max\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\}$ if $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$.

I managed to show that $f$ has order $\leq \max\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\}$ showing that for every $\epsilon>0$, $|f(z)|<\exp(|z|^{\max\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\}+\epsilon})$ for sufficiently large, but I'm stuck in the rest of the question. I was thinking in prove that $\lambda$ must be a lower bound to the set $\{a;|f(z)|<\exp(|z|^a) \text{ for }|f| \text{ sufficiently large}\}$, so this will say that $\lambda$ it's the infimun, i.e. the order of $f$.

Thank you.

Comment: assume for definitness $\lambda_2 < \lambda_1$ and then using that $|f_2| <<\exp(|z|^{\lambda_1-\delta})$ for some fixed $\delta>0$, use a sequence $|f_1(z_n)| >> \exp(|z|^{\lambda_1-\epsilon})$ and the triangle inequality to show that $|f(z_n)| >> \exp(|z|^{\lambda_1-\epsilon})$ for a fixed $\epsilon>0$ small etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$. You already showed that the order $\lambda $ of  $f$ is at most $ \max (\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \lambda_2$.

By the same argument, applied to $f_2 = f + (-f_1)$, is
$$
 \lambda_2 \le \max(\lambda, \lambda_1) = \lambda
$$
since the maximum can not be $\lambda_1$.

Therefore $\lambda = \lambda_2 = \max (\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$.